# How can I make a dropdown menu within my current menu

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

I currently have a navigation menu with a few subjects. One subject has the titel Equipment. When I hover over it, Throwables and Gear show up. This is what I currently have, I want to have another menu that opens when I hover over Throwables or Gear. I tried different things like adding another ul or li between the li of Gear, but every time when I trie something like that my hole menu get weird. I searched on YouTube/Google but I couldn't get it to work how I want it.

So in short:
I want another dropdown menu when I hover over Throwables or Gear. It needs to open to the right and have the same blue color when I hover over it, [Here is an example of how it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgiGq.png) (the rest of the menu is to the left of Equipment)

A part of the menu code:

```css
.navigatie_menu{
  position: absolute;
  left: 505px;
  top: 95px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(223,223,223,0.95);
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: black;
}

    ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block; 
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #94bfea;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="navigatie_menu">
  <li><a>Equipment</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Equipment/Gear.html">Gear</a></li>
      <li><a href="Equipment/Throwables.html">Throwables</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```css
        .navigatie_menu {
            position: absolute;
            left: 505px;
            top: 95px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        ul {
            padding: 0px;
            list-style: none;
            color: black;
        }

        ul li {
            float: left;
            width: 130px;
            height: 40px;
            background: rgba(223, 223, 223, 0.95);
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 17px;
            color: black;
        }

        ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
            display: block;
        }

        ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #94bfea;
            display: block;
        }

        ul li ul li {
            display: none;
        }

        ul li:hover ul li {
            display: block;
        }

        .sub_menu1 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 130px;
            display: none;
        }

        .sub_menu2 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 130px;
            display: none;
        }


        .gear:hover .sub_menu1 {
            display: block;
        }

        .throwables:hover .sub_menu2 {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class="navigatie_menu">
        <li><a>Equipment</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="gear"><a href="Equipment/Gear.html">Gear</a>
                    <ul class="sub_menu1">
                        <li><a href="#">subject1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">subject2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">subject3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">subject4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="throwables"><a href="Equipment/Throwables.html">Throwables</a>
                    <ul class="sub_menu2">
                        <li><a href="#">subject1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">subject2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">subject3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">subject4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I ment. Thank you very much!!